# Why does the search results change after PDF optimization in Ghostscript?

Tags: imagemagick, ghostscript

When searching for the word find in the PDF file in this [Link](http://manuals.info.apple.com/MANUALS/1000/MA1658/en_US/iphone_ios6_user_guide.pdf) before Ghostscript optimization the results will give pages number 4,7 and 13 but after the optimization it gives only pages 4 and 13 ignoring page number 7, the script im using for the optimization :

```
D:/gswin64c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dMaxSubsetPct=100 -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dMaxInlineImageSize=0 -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook -dColorImageResolution=96 -dDetectDuplicateImages=true -dColorImageDownsampleThreshold=1.1 -dDOPDFMARKS -dUseTrimBox -sOutputFile="D:/temp/search_text.pdf" -dNOPAUSE -dNOGC -dBATCH  -dNumRenderingThreads=8 -c 50000000 setvmthreshold -f "D:/temp/iphone_user_guide.pdf"
```

I've tried to add several fonts related parameters to the script such as -dEmbedAllFonts=true and pointing to fonts path also I've tried to play with the parameters by eliminating some but with no result 
what could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript doesn't do 'optimization'. See my answer here:

[GhostScript issues with a CropBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505001/ghostscript-issues-with-a-cropbox/25506994#25506994)

for some details on what it does do.

Wihtout seeing your file I cannot tell you for certain what the difference is, but most likely the missing text has been drawn as images instead of text for some reason.

By the way, a lot of the options you are sending have absolutely no effect (eg NumRenderingThreads, for a device which doesn't do rendering). You should NOT select -dNOGC, that's a really bad idea, -dDOPDFMARKS is already set for the pdfwrite device.

Comment: If you click in the link in my question you could find the file however how can i make sure that the file is optimized and the text is moved as text not drawn as an image?

Comment: As I pointed out in the link, Ghostscript and pdfwrite don't 'optimize' a file at all.The basic reason is that your original PDF file has a peculiar ToUnicode CMAp, and the resulting ToUnicode CMap produced by pdfwrite isn't the same, so you get a strange result. For what its worth, the 'f' in find on that page isn't an 'f', its an fi ligature, so the ToUnicode map has to have two characters, 0x0066 and 0x0069 that seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers but i have these final questions how did you came out with this result the peculiar unicode result? and the next part that 'f' isn't an 'f'? and what do you recommend to leave the text as it is?

Comment: I deompressed the PDF file and read the contents, including the ToUnicode CMap. I don't understand your final question, the text is 'left as it is'.

Comment: i meant how can we preserve the text as it is after this operation? in another words how can i keep the resulting ToUnicode CMap in the new PDF the same as the one in the original, for example using a gs parameter or something similar?

Comment: The text is preserved. You can't preserve the ToUnicode CMap unchanged, because pdfwrite (or possibly the PDF interpreter) fails to do so. You could open a bug report (hint: don't attach the complete, large, file, just the offending page will do)

Comment: Thank you @Kens I've up-voted the answer for answering the rest :)